# Cannot call a function inside a then method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I am trying to call two functions one within another

commonService Components

```
function AddEmail(user) {
    return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,user.password);    
    //createUsers(user) this way of calling is working, but i don't want to invoke like this...
}

function createUsers(user) {
    return db.collection("users").add({
        firstName: user.firstName,
        lastName:  user.lastName,
        address:  user.address,
        phoneNumber:  user.phoneNumber,
        email:  user.email,
        role:  user.role,
    });
}
```

register component

```
submits(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    const { user} = this.state;
        
    commonService.AddEmail(user)
    .then(() => {
        commonService.createUsers(user)
        .then(() =>{//success})
        .catch(err=> console.log(err));
    })
    .catch(err=> console.log(err));
}
```

The `AddEmail` gets executed, but not the `createUsers`. I've tried returning and chaining via *then* method too, still its not working, what am I missing?

Comment: question: you're calling `commonService.createUsers`, which, without any further details or code, is not the function you're showing. That's just a plain, in-scope `createUsers`. So: what's `commonService.createUsers`?

Comment: Try using [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) / [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) functions instead of `then`. You will have a much easier time debugging the code. 

Comment: Most likely `commonService.AddEmail(user)` failed. 
`commonService.createUsers(user)` gets called in success case.

Comment: `commonService.AddEmail(users)` works just fine. The problem occurs when the `createUsers(user)` is called in the `commonService.AddEmail(users)`'s then method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following with `async / await`.

```
async submit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const { user} = this.state;

    try {
        const userEmailAdded = await commonService.AddEmail(user);
        const userCreated = await commonService.createUsers(user);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Make sure to return a promise in both the function calls. If the return value is not a promise, wrap it in a promise using the following code

```
function AddEmail(user) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject){
        const createdUser = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,user.password);
        if(createdUser)
            return resolve(createdUser);
        else
            return reject("Error in creating user.");
    })
}
```

Check for any errors in console. If none, both calls passed.

Comment: this is not working, just want to know why i cannot call a then method inside another one...

Comment: You can call. My guess is that the `AddEmail` function is not returning a `Promise`. Can you share the return value of that function?

Comment: I am sorry async / await works... i forgot to change the `createUsers(user)` to async function. Now it works fine.

Comment: Thanks @Navisgero. You can upvote the answer if it's right.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code.

```js
submits(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    const { user} = this.state;
        
    commonService.AddEmail(user)
    .then(() => commonService.createUsers(user))
    .then(() =>{//success})
    .catch(err=> console.log(err));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,user.password);
```

The returning function must be a javascript **Promise** to use a **.then**.

You can try to `console.log(auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword)` whether it is a Promise or not.